# Javascript object: backreference to property name

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I am trying to ease the creation of the content of a javascript object so that values depend on member names, something like this:

```
var obj = {
    1: "you selected 1",
    2: "wow, you selected 2",
    3: "this time, you selected " + myName(), //myName() gets resolved to 3
    137: "I think you've chosen " + myName() + " this time.", //myName() gets resolved to 137
    513: myName() + " is the answer!" //myName() gets resolved to 513
};
```

Is that possible to backreference the member name in the definition of the value, using somethink like the supposed function **myName()**?

If no native method exists, what is the recommended way to accomplish this?

You may ask **"Why does this guy need this stange way of generating objects??"**, and the answer is: in my code, member/field names may change, default values will be copied with the only difference being the reference to the member name, and I don't want to define number values in each key-value pair twice, hence I am after a way of backreferencing the name inside the value definition.

Comment: So basically you want to get key of your object in its value right?
Something like `obj ={ "dave" : "my name is "+key}` here key will resolve into dave.

Comment: yes, I want the value to be able to get the key. The 'key' will be the same keyword but will return different numbers for values with different keys.

Comment: I've been thinking about using a special string, like "@key@", and replace it later, but there is the remote possibility of somebody wanting to use the string '@key@' in the value and ending up making a code injection

Comment: Hmm.. sounds good to me, but i don't want us to get key hardcoded. How will we send it to the function without hardcoding it.

Comment: if you know the key before hand, can't you do obj[key] = 'blabla' + key ?

Comment: well, yes, but... sorry, I failed to explain that the key will not necessarily appear at the end of the value. I will edit the question to address this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for an ES6 feature, [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

> The `Proxy` object is used to define custom behavior for fundamental operations (e.g. property lookup, assignment, enumeration, function invocation, etc).

Then take the `prop` with the actual key and replace the placeholder `{key}` with the actual key.

```js
var obj = {
        1: "you selected {key}",
        2: "wow, you selected {key}",
        3: "this time, you selected {key}",
        137: "I think you've chosen {key} this time.",
        513: "{key} is the answer!"
    },
    p = new Proxy(obj, {
        get: function(target, prop) {
            return target[prop] && target[prop].replace("{key}", prop);
        }
    });

console.log(p[3]);          // this time, you selected 3
console.log(p[137]);        // I think you've chosen 137 this time.
console.log(p[513]);        // 513 is the answer!
obj.foo = 'This is {key}!'; // create new property foo
console.log(p.foo);         // This is foo!
obj.bar = obj.foo;          // assign foo to bar
delete obj.foo;             // delete foo
console.log(p.foo);         // undefined
console.log(p.bar);         // This is bar!
```

Comment: I could not understand the benefit of the Proxy. Seems like just a replace would do the job. The solution reserves the "{key}" substring. If no solution is able to escape to the code instead of reserving strings, I'll accepts yours.

Comment: @EduardoPoço, the proxy has access to the name of the called property.

Comment: Oh, now I see, the replace is made when the value is requested. The original object is left with the substring "{key}", so only outside code which accesses the object through the proxy sees the replacement, right? So that's why the name is Proxy!

Comment: @EduardoPoço, right. the proxy's get is called and the actual key is replaced.

Answer (score 0):

After all, I figured out a way to accomplish my desire, if somebody is still interested.

I used functions in the values instead of strings. The functions are evaluated and return the values using the key where it is needed, according to the function. So it becomes:

```
var obj = {
    1: function(key){return "you selected 1";},
    2: function(key){return "wow, you selected 2";},
    3: function(key){return "this time, you selected " + key;},
    137: function(key){return "I think you've chosen " + key + " this time.";},
    513: function(key){return key + " is the answer!";}
};

function getValue(key) {
    return obj[key](key);
}
```

To call for the value, use:

```
var value = getValue(137);
```

No string is reserved for replaces, as the OP (myself) is paranoid with this.